# Converting Unicodestring to Char[]

Tags: char, c++builder

I've got a form with a Listbox which contains lines of four words.
When I click on one line, these words should be seen in four different textboxes.
So far, I've got everything working, yet I have a problem with chars converting.

The string from the listbox is a UnicodeString but the strtok uses a char[].
The compiler tells me it "Cannot Convert UnicodeString to Char[]". This is the code I am using for this:

```
{
 int a;
 UnicodeString b;

 char * pch;
 int c;

 a=DatabaseList->ItemIndex;   //databaselist is the listbox
 b=DatabaseList->Items->Strings[a]; 

 char str[] = b; //This is the part that fails, telling its unicode and not char[].
 pch = strtok (str," ");      
 c=1;                          
 while (pch!=NULL)
    {
       if (c==1)
       {
          ServerAddress->Text=pch;
       } else if (c==2)
       {
          DatabaseName->Text=pch;
       } else if (c==3)
       {
          Username->Text=pch;
       } else if (c==4)
       {
          Password->Text=pch;
       }
       pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
       c=c+1;
    }
}
```

I know my code doesn't look nice, pretty bad actually. I'm just learning some programming in C++.

How can I convert this?

Comment: Please try the ICU library u_strToUTF8 for example

Comment: Can you explain **why** that should be neccessary, and how that should be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

strtok actually modifies your char array, so you will need to construct an array of characters you are allowed to modify.  Referencing directly into the UnicodeString string will not work.

```
// first convert to AnsiString instead of Unicode.
AnsiString ansiB(b);  

// allocate enough memory for your char array (and the null terminator)
char* str = new char[ansiB.Length()+1];  

// copy the contents of the AnsiString into your char array 
strcpy(str, ansiB.c_str());  

// the rest of your code goes here

// remember to delete your char array when done
delete[] str;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I am goin to find out how it worked what you did, but it worked!

Comment: I recently edited my post to make the char array of length ansiB.Length()+1.  This is important.  Make sure you make that change or you could get random crashes.

Comment: I do get an error after closing the program. When i used the code you provided, i get an acces violation, when i break it jumps to Forms.hpp 
/* TCustomForm.Destroy */ inline __fastcall virtual ~TForm(void) { }
Could that mean that there is something going wrong with the str or something?

Comment: haha excellent, didn't catch you in time. It works like a charm! Thank you fo ryour support!!!

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Remember to accept an answer as the correct one.

Comment: using `std::string`, or `std::vector<char>` instead of `new`+`strcpy` makes your code easier to maintain and safe in the case of exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and saves me converting to AnsiString

```
// Using a static buffer
#define MAX_SIZE 256
UnicodeString ustring = "Convert me";
char mbstring[MAX_SIZE];

    wcstombs(mbstring,ustring.c_str(),MAX_SIZE);

// Using dynamic buffer
char *dmbstring;

    dmbstring = new char[ustring.Length() + 1];
    wcstombs(dmbstring,ustring.c_str(),ustring.Length() + 1);
    // use dmbstring
    delete dmbstring;
```